# Please is there a way I can solve this error I think everything is well with this

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I have suffered from this error, please help me.[image: is an error]

this is my views.py and models.py file please I need to create add to cart function, and this error one happens when I click the add to cart button using get_or_create function.
here is the code:

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
    return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Take a look in line 966 as is mentioned in the Traceback.

Comment: Can you share your urls.py and the `a` element you use for this URL